Why can't I read other attributes from a CATIA Macro?
We encountered an issue during our CATIA macro development.
We get an error when we try to read the value of an attribute on VPMReference (attribute name: PLMReference.V_hasConfigContext) in the macro. The error we received is attached (see error.png).
When we try to read a different attribute (attribute name: PLMReference.V_isLastVersion) on the same interface, we can read it without any problems.
The full code is below (macro.cs).
How can I read the value of the V_hasConfigContext attribute?
Thanks in advance.
Code: macro.cs
using System;
using VPMEditorContextIDL;

namespace Macro_library_VSTA00000042_vst00000042_1
{
    public sealed partial class ThisApplication : ObjectModelAgentLib.CATIAEntryPoint
    {
    
        // public static void CATMain()
        // {
        //    // Debug entry point, not visible from the host
        //    CATIA.SystemService.PrintToStdout("Hello, World! C#");
        // }

        public static void Macro1()
        {
            try
            {

                var productService = (PLMProductService)CATIA.ActiveEditor.GetService("PLMProductService");

                var root = productService.RootOccurrence.PLMEntity;

                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show((bool)root.GetAttributeValue("V_isLastVersion") + "");
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show((bool)root.GetAttributeValue("V_hasConfigContext") + "");
                

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            

        }

    }
}


Doesn't look as if this relation to VBA?!

I removed vba tag. Sorry for that. @FunThomas

To which class should V_hasConfigContex belonge? According PLMEntity has no V_hasConfigContext attribute.

I do not know exactly. Is there a way to search in the help page in your post? I searched V_hasConfigContext but no result. I have to find the class as you said.

@Lyrk please check the hopefully locally installed help file.
